# Can both the GPU and CPU versions of PyTorch be installed in the same Conda environment?

Tags: python, gpu, pytorch, cpu, conda

The [PyTorch installation web page](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) shows how to install the GPU and CPU versions of PyTorch:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
```

and

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
```

Can both version be installed in the same `Conda` environment?

In case you might ask why would this be needed, it's because I would like a single `Conda` environment which I can use on computers which have a GPU and those which don't.

Comment: Regardless of installing 2 versions in one env, I don't think you can have PyTorch GPU installed on a machine without NVidia GPU, because it depends on CUDA.

Answer (score 11):

The GPU version of PyTorch is actually a superset of the CPU PyTorch. You can use the GPU PyTorch on a CPU, but you cannot use the CPU PyTorch on a GPU. So in your case, installing just the GPU version of PyTorch would be sufficient.

Comment: are your sure? I initially installed the torch gpu version and used it for training and testing. Now for my flask app i don't need to run it on gpu. I load the model to cpu (explicitly) and i get the error CUDA out of memory. This is weird!

Comment: Can you provide some example on how can you use GPU PyTorch on CPU? Because I tend to disagree on this